# How to check feature importances on text feature?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, sentiment-analysis

First of all, I'm still doing study about classifier comparison on sentiment analysis. Then, I want to know for every feature importances on each classifier.

I've already tried `model.feature_importances_`, but because I vectorize my data train, I can't understand what word is on those feature importances.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

line = pd.read_csv('line_label.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

x = line.Berita
y = line.Sentimen

xcv = x
xtf = x

countvect = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word", tokenizer = None, lowercase = None)
xcv = countvect.fit_transform(x).toarray()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xcv, y, test_size=0.01, random_state=42)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 

rf = RandomForestClassifier() 

rf.fit(X_train, y_train) 

rf.score(X_test, y_test)

rf.feature_importances_
```

It shows

```
array([2.20854745e-04, 1.24760561e-04, 3.14268988e-03, ...,
   1.71782391e-04, 5.15755286e-05, 2.13065348e-08])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
for feature, importance in zip(countvect.get_feature_names(), rf.feature_importances_):
    print('{}: {}'.format(feature, importance))
```